# Aligning material edittexts, textviews, checkboxes, etc

Tags: android

My probles is that all of these views have different left padding, and when I place them one below another it looks messy.

How do I fix it? Is there any cool way to solve this issue?

I tried to to put some additional paddings, like 2dp for edittexts and 4dp for textviews, but it doesn't seem to work because of different paddings on different devices.

Example (in Googles official applications this is not the case):
[image]
Here nothing special in my layouts, just views without any additional attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dip">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/network_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_password"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share your layout please.

Answer (score 4):

There is no cool way to do this. The following strategy works best for me:

- Add all Views to my XML
- run [Material Cue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actinarium.materialcue) on my phone to draw a grid
- adjust padding/margins until everything matches the grid (very fast with [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run))
- check for cropped ripple effects. Optionally add [`android:clipChildren="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) or [`android:clipToPadding="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipToPadding)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a padding to each view, you should put one to the layout which contains the form. This way, all views will be correctly aligned.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <!--Your form inputs-->

</LinearLayout>
```

A newly created activity already has a padding of 16dp all around the root layout.

The value '16dp' should be saved as a *dimen*, not hardcoded.

Comment: Yes, thats how it is done in my activities/dialogs. The problem is that every built in material control already has different padding.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to manage margin and padding this way:

1. Under `/res/` create multiple `values` folder depending on screen densities (e.g. `values-w820dp`) then create `dimens.xml` under those folders with the proper values for each screen densities. [follow this guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).
2. If possible, **always use RelativeLayout** instead of LinearLayout. If your problem is just alignment then you can always use attributes of `RelativeLayout` like `android:layout_alignRight="@id/id_of_view"` to manage alignments.